# Tax setup for India

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, setup

I need to setup taxation for Indian region.
For intrastate the tax is VAT 5%.
For interstate the tax is CST 5%.
I need the cart to automatically calculate tax based on the state i.e. for home state it should be shown as VAT 5% and for other states it should be shown as CST 5% in the invoice. 
Can anyone help me in achieving this.
I m using magento 1.9

Comment: have you got solution for this ?